# properties under beans tag for spring mvc application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I read a bean code under `spring-app.xml`

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mmi.education.dao.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Instead of property **annotatedClasses**, I want to specify the package.

Is it possible?

Also what are the valid properties that can be specified under bean tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mmi.education.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Check Spring's documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html) for other properties.